# Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.TreeMap<java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.Double>`

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is the GitHub repo of my Spring Boot application that I have trouble with: [click me](https://github.com/HanYuanHsu/shepherd-money/tree/master).

I was trying to do `./gradlew bootRun` to start this application, but then I got the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
15:06:01.730 ERROR --- [           main] o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:820 : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.TreeMap<java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.Double>`
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.InterviewProjectApplication.main(InterviewProjectApplication.java:32)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.TreeMap<java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.Double>`
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:507)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:315)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:305)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767)
hankevin@DESKTOP-CH9NBS4:/mnt/c/Users/a0306/shepherd-money$
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1766)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
        ... 16 common frames omitted

> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I saw the sentence "Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.TreeMap<java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.Double>`". Here is the CreditCard class, which has a variable `balanceHistory` of the type:

```
package com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.model;

import com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.TreeMap;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CreditCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String issuanceBank;

    private String number;

    private int userId; // the id of the user

    private TreeMap<LocalDate, Double> balanceHistory = new TreeMap<>();

    public CreditCard(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;

        // initialize balance history. It must have a date value that matches today's date.
        balanceHistory.put(LocalDate.now(), 0.0);
    }

    public CreditCard(String issuanceBank, String number, int userId) {
        this.issuanceBank = issuanceBank;
        this.number = number;
        this.userId = userId;

        // initialize balance history. It must have a date value that matches today's date.
        balanceHistory.put(LocalDate.now(), 0.0);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ur the user repo of this application
     * @return the name of this credit card's owner
     */
    public String getUsername(UserRepository ur) {
        User u = ur.findById(userId).orElseThrow();
        return u.getName();
    }

    // TODO: Credit card's balance history. It is a requirement that the dates in the balanceHistory 
    //       list must be in chronological order, with the most recent date appearing first in the list. 
    //       Additionally, the first object in the list must have a date value that matches today's date, 
    //       since it represents the current balance of the credit card. For example:
    //       [
    //         {date: '2023-04-13', balance: 1500},
    //         {date: '2023-04-12', balance: 1200},
    //         {date: '2023-04-11', balance: 1000},
    //         {date: '2023-04-10', balance: 800}
    //       ]

    /**
     * Given `date` and `balance`, update this credit card's balance history.
     * Update means to add `balance` to the current balance at the date specified by `date`
     * @param date
     * @param balance
     */
    public void updateBalance(LocalDate date, double balance) {
        double currentBalance = balanceHistory.getOrDefault(date, 0.0);
        balanceHistory.put(date, currentBalance + balance);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's really a table in itself isn't it? It should probably be its own entity

Comment: @g00se What do you mean by table?

Comment: In a fully normalized RDBMS, that `Map` you have would be represented by its own table

Comment: Would you mind answering below how I would implement it as an entity?

Comment: You could simply have a `class BalanceHistory { private Map<LocalDate, Double> balanceHistory = new TreeMap<>(); }` Keep the `Map` implementation open. For one thing, changes in collections are on the horizon in Java